# How can I make a key press down combination of two keys Ctrl + S?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SaveGameTest : MonoBehaviour
{
    public SaveLoad saveLoad;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftControl) && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
        {
            saveLoad.SaveWithTime();
        }
    }
}
```

Doing it this way just does nothing.

Using a breakpoint on the line :

```
saveLoad.SaveWithTime();
```

It's never getting to this line if I press on Ctrl only or on S only or on both at the same time Ctrl + S

I want the combination Ctrl + S for saving.

But I see that Ctrl + S is busy by the editor when I press on Ctrl + S I see the message :

[image: Message]

So I have two problems :

1. How to make a combination of keys press down at the same time?
2. What combination keys can be logic for saving if Ctrl + S is taken already by the editor ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlikely you press down both buttons in the exact same frame. See [`Input.GetKeyDown`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyDown.html)

> Returns true during **the frame** the user **starts pressing** down the key identified by the key KeyCode enum parameter.

Rather track a **continuous** press for the first one using [`Input.GetKey`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKey.html)

> Returns true **while** the user **holds down** the key identified by the key KeyCode enum parameter.

```
if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftControl) && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
```

---

If Unity doesn't allow CTRL+S at all then you could *fake* it using [Platform dependent compilation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html) like e.g.

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftAlt) && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftControl) && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
#else
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftControl) && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
#endif
```

So only for the editor it is CTRL+ALT+S while later in a built application it will be CTRL+S